# Centrar Logout con usuario en MVC de net.core Identity

Tags: css, mvc, identity

alguien sabe como poder centrar estos dos elementos? He probado de todo y no lo logro... Un saludo, muchas gracias!

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¡Hola, @Diego Ruiz! Si dejas el código alguien podrá ayudar. Únicamente con la imagen es, literalmente, imposible ayudarte con algo. Deberías leer [ask] y [mcve]  para que tus preguntas sean mejor recibidas :)